# why can't it populate the whole list of products

Tags: php

I don't know what is wrong with my code.
supposingly,
it should be populating all the items that I have in my database(id)
however,
it just tell me how many item I have in my database instead of listing out all the ids of products that I have in my database

Can someone help to pointed out my mistakes?
I'm following a tutorial on youtube on making the shopping cart.

```
<?php
$product_list = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supermarket");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//count output amount
if($productCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $product_list = "$id<br>";
    }
}
else{
    $product_list = "You have no products listed in your store yet";
}
?>
```

Comment: You are erasing $product_list content every time you pass inside the loop. The only thing stocked inside $product_list is the last id in your query.

Comment: you overwrite your $product_list every sequence of your loop. store in in a array: `$product_list[] = "$id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time round your `while` loop, you're overwriting the previous contents of `$product_list`. You presumably want to concatenate instead using the `.=` operator, like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_list .= "$id<br>";
}
```

I'm assuming here that you're outputting `$product_list` later (some time after the loop), e.g.:

```
echo $product_list;
```

Answer (score 4):

You're overwriting your `$product_list` variable. Instead you need to take all your id in array variable,

```
$product_list = array();
if($productCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row["id"];
        $product_list[] = $id;
    }
}
print_r($product_list);
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: This is not a complete code. You need to add this after your line `$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);`. Just replace this with your current `if condition`.

Comment: What is the column name for `item id` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all data from your product:

```
$product_list = array();
  if($productCount > 0){
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row["id"];
    $product_list[$id] = $row;
  }
}
print_r($product_list);
```

you have to store it in a array, you overwrite you $product_list every sequence of the while loop
its not the count you get btw, its the last id fetched you get returned in your code